# Android AVD error No, minSdk(API 16) > deviceSdk(API 1)

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to run the AVD that I created, it returns the error `No, minSdk(API 16) > deviceSdk(API 1)`

If it helps I am using a computer with AMD processor

I researched on topics that others have posted the same problem but all were in specific cases that using an external device to run the application.

**My build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "luizugliano.com.br.minhaagendadecontatos"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Error

[image]

AVD

[image]

[image]

My SDK Manager

[image]

Comment: Do you have the developer options enabled? Also, when you run the command "adb devices" on the terminal, do you see your device listed?

Comment: trying to run in emulator.? make sure emulator configurations matches the build requirements

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the SDK version of your Virtual Device or Physical Device is 1, but in your build.gradle has declare that the minSDK is 16, so you have to create a new Virtual Device with API 16 or a major version, or connect a Device whit API 16 or major.

Regards.

Comment: Hello, I updated the question with new screens. Note that the configuration is correct and the error continues.

Comment: Ok, try to create a Genymotion Virtual Device, its work better, faster and it's free for personal use, and another option is Xamarin Player.

Comment: Personally AVD never works for my, the devices almost never's get starts